# Find position of elements in one vector in another in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have a vector `needle = [3 2 6];` and I want to find the index of its elements in another vector `haystack = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];`. The result to be returned is of same dimension as `needle` and in this case would be `[4 3 7]`. The elements of `needle` are not necessarily unique. I have already implemented this using a function file using for-loops. An implementation using `ismember` could work, but you run into problems if two or more elements in `needle` are the same, since `ismember` will return a single '1' for all the elements in `needle` that are the same.

```
    find(haystack == needle)
```

will also not work as haystack and needle may not be of the same dimension.

Is there a neat, *one-liner* that I could use to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Just that yours was a cell array in your question. The post could be closed I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ismember` does work, but you'll want the second output:

```
[~, ind] = ismember(needle, haystack)
```

e.g.

```
needle = [3 2 6 6];
haystack = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
[~, ind] = ismember(needle, haystack)

ind =

   4   3   7   7
```

Comment: The behaviour seems to be different if needle and haystack are complex numbers. Do you know why?

Comment: no - complex number work for me. I wonder if your issue is precision related? If your complex numbers are double precision, then perhaps a value in needle you think is in haystack actually differs by a tiny value. Pick a number and try compare them directly (e.g. `needle(31) == haystack(415)`)

Answer (score 1):

1. If each member of `needle` is guaranteed to appear **at least once** in `haystack`, you can use `bsxfun` and then the second output `max`:

   ```
   [~, where] = max(bsxfun(@eq, needle, haystack.'))
   ```

   If an element of `needle` appears more than once, this will give you the index of its *first* appearance.
2. If the elements of `needle` **may not appear** in `haystack`, you can modify the code above to return `NaN` (for example) in that case:

   ```
   [val, where] = max(bsxfun(@eq, needle, haystack.'));
   where(~val) = NaN
   ```
3. In the most general case, if you want to get **all (if any)** appearances of each element of `needle` in `haystack`:

   ```
   cellfun(@find,mat2cell(bsxfun(@eq,needle,haystack.'),numel(haystack),ones(1,numel(needle))),'uni',false)
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   >> needle = [4 2 5 8];
   >> haystack = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 7];
   >> cellfun(@find,mat2cell(bsxfun(@eq, needle, haystack.'),numel(haystack),ones(1,numel(needle))),'uni',false)

   ans = 

   [5]    [3]    [2x1 double]    [0x1 double]

   >> ans{3}

   ans =

        6
        8
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work for you, answer is a 1x3 array

```
answer = [find(haystack==needle(1)),find(haystack==needle(2)),find(haystack==needle(3))];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nah. I don't always know the size of needle, so this is not portable. I would have to use for-loops and the size function if I am to use your implementation.